# Need to stop jenkins pipeline multiple times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I running our maven project on a jenkins server with multiple stages inside the pipeline.
Every time I decide that the branch test does not need to continue and click on abort in the jenkins ui, I need to repeat this many times until the jenkins pipeline really stops.
I guess that our jenkinsfile does not really pick up that the job was aborted and I need to abort every stage to come to the end.

Is there a way to help jenkins to get out of the pipeline?
For example a variable I can check?

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        if (!currentBuild.isAborted) {
            stage('Unit Tests') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Unit Testing'
                }
            }
        }
        if (!currentBuild.isAborted) {
            stage('Deploy') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Deploying'
                }
            }
        }
        if (!currentBuild.isAborted) {
            stage('Backend Integration Tests') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Backend Int Tests'
                }
            }
        }
        if (!currentBuild.isAborted) {
            stage('Frontend Integration Tests') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Deploying....'
                }
            }
        }
        // done
    }
}
```

Comment: is this persistent across multiple pipeline jobs or just this one? How are you triggering the job?

Comment: The job is triggered by jenkins when a developer pushes his changes into git.

Comment: how many times is it triggerd per push? what happens of you manaully rung the job? can you kill it in one click?

Comment: No it is started only once per push. Does not make a difference if you start manually or automatically. Same behaviour.

Comment: happens to me as well. I just pass `/stop` at the end of the jenkins url and press enter. the page reloads and asks to `Retry Using POST` and I click. even after clicking it still points the same Retry page. But the job gets stopped this way easily. I was able to do this via curl from command line. This is not a solution clearly. But can be considered a workaround.